# Swapping specific properties of two nodes including relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to swap multiple properties and all relationships between two nodes in Neo4j.
For example-

```
Node 1 -> {id='id1',name:'ABC',city='London'} belongs to A
Node 2 -> {id='ID1',name:'PQR',city='Paris'} belongs to B
```

After Query Execution, the result should be-

```
Node 1 -> {id='id1',name:'PQR',city='Paris'} will belong to B
Node 2 -> {id='ID1',name:'ABC',city='London'} will belong to A
```

Note: id is case-sensitive hence two nodes with similar text are present. We don't want to swap id property.

Tried doing it with `set properties(node)` and Temp node like-

```
MATCH
  (node1 {id: 'id1'}),
  (node2 {id: 'ID1'})
CREATE (Temp:Student{properties(node1)}) 
AND SET node1.name = node2.name, node1.city = node2.city
AND SET node2.name = Temp.name, node2.city = Temp.city
AND DELETE Temp 
RETURN node1,node2
```

Getting following error

```
Invalid input '(': expected "}" (line 4, column 33 (offset: 99))
"CREATE (Temp:Student{properties(node1)})"
```

Wanted to know if it's possible without creating a Temp node.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) clause to store temporary values. Assuming both nodes have the `Student` label, this query should work:

```
MATCH
  (n1:Student {id: 'id1'}),
  (n2:Student {id: 'ID1'})
WITH n1, n2, n1.name AS name1, n1.city AS city1
SET
  n1.name = n2.name, n1.city = n2.city,
  n2.name = name1, n2.city = city1
RETURN n1, n2
```

Comment: This is the cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

Below query works for me:

```
MATCH (node1:Student {id: 'id1'}),(node2:Student {id: 'ID1'}) 
CREATE (temp:Student) 
SET temp  = properties(node1),
    node1.name = node2.name, node1.city = node2.city,
    node2.name = temp.name, node2.city = temp.city
DELETE temp
RETURN node1, node2
```

Ref: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-copying-properties-between-nodes-and-relationships

Without specifying the node label Student, it is not working for me.  So I need to put the label node1:Student instead of just node1.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would write the query. You had the right structure, but there were a couple of syntax issues. The biggest one was that you need to use a SET clause when you create the Temp node. To answer your question whether we can avoid creating a temp node, I don't believe that's possible because you typically overwrite existing properties. And, if you don't overwrite them, you would have to retain/track the old properties to move over.

```
MATCH
  (node1 {id: 'id1'}),
  (node2 {id: 'ID1'})
CREATE (Temp:Student {id: node1.id})
 SET Temp = properties(node1) 
WITH node1, node2, Temp
 SET node1 += {name: node2.name, city: node2.city},
     node2 += {name: Temp.name, city: Temp.city}
DELETE Temp 
RETURN node1, node2
```

Links for syntax I used are here:

- Copy properties: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-copying-properties-between-nodes-and-relationships
- Mutate properties: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-setting-properties-using-map